# How do I require a nodeJS module in a parent directory to a sym linked folder

Tags: linux, node.js

i have this folder structure:

```
-folder1
    myTasks.js
-node_modules
    gulp
gulpfile.js
```

the contents of myTasks.js is:

```
module.exports = function () {

    var gulp = require('gulp');

    gulp.task('myTask', function () {});
};
```

the contents of gulpfile.js is:

```
var tasks = require('./folder1/myTasks.js');

tasks();
```

then from the command line i can type (i have gulp-cli installed globally):

```
gulp myTask
```

all is fine and dandy and my gulp task executes.

in reality folder1 used to be a git submodule, which i want to get away from. When I locate folder1 elsewhere and create a symlink (ln -s path/to/folder folder1) still with myTasks.js in it and i type again:

```
gulp myTask
```

i get the node error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'gulp'
//...
at module.exports (/myTasks.js.js:8:16)
at Object.<anonymous> (/gulpfile.js:12:1)
//...
```

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

If you put a link to the `node_modules` that is in the parent of `folder1` in `folder1`. i.e. `cd folder1; ln ../node_modules node_modules`. Your linking will work.